# Pycharm stucks with Launching skeleton generator proccess

Tags: docker-compose, pycharm

I use Ubuntu 20.04, Pycharm 2020.3.3, Docker version 20.10.4, docker-compose version 1.28.2,

I have configured Python remote interpreter via docker-compose. When I open Pycharm I see a process `Launching skeleton generator...` running. It runs very long time, more than 30 minutes. While that code completion is broken and error highlighting doesn't work. Eventually finishes with error:

> Couldn't refresh skeletons for remote interpreter
> failed to run generator3/**main**.py for docker-compose://[/home/belek/Work/project/docker-compose.yml]:app-name/pyhon:timed out.

What I tried to do in order to resolve problem:

- `docker system prune -a`
- Recreated python remote interpreter
- Invalidate caches and Restart Pycharm

Today morning I got latest updates of docker and compose, and probably this problem starts to occure.

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Upd:
As a temporary solution downgraded Docker to 20.10.3

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce=5:20.10.3~3-0~ubuntu-focal docker-ce-cli=5:20.10.3~3-0~ubuntu-focal containerd.io
```

Also found an [issue in YT](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-47427).